# Binding native C library to dart using dart:ffi

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use dart:ffi to import a C library so I can use the functions in my dart code. I am following the [instructions on the Flutter website](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop) to do this. I am currently on [step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ylOF.png), and the dart code is looking for a .so file, but it was not created from the previous steps. Does anyone know what to do in order to get that file? I am using a computer running WindowsOS.

Comment: It should be generate on build with CMake.